# Should I create a class for functions that execute spesific SQL functions?

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller

I have a PHP application which is pretty simple: It allows the user to create, edit and read a post. Basic stuff.

I have a `Database` class which handles the connection and the queries execution. The thing is that I want my models (I am using a self-built MVC framework) to be clean, so I created in `Database` some functions such as `CreatePost()`, `EditPost()` etc., which contains all the SQL needed, so I can call them nicely from the model: `$database->CreatePost(/* post data */);`.

**Should I keep those functions in the `Database` class, or should I put them elsewhere (let's say, a class)? Maybe I should even give up on the functions idea and write the code explicitly in the model?**

---

**EDIT:**

As [@Tanuel Mategi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3338286/tanuel-mategi) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269228/should-i-create-a-class-for-functions-that-uses-of-the-database?noredirect=1#comment54339592_33269228), the answer is probably opinion-based, but still - I am trying to figure out what most of the people would do according to well-accepted modern conventions, and particularly the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). So, is that one responsability or not?

Comment: This is purely opinion based i guess. i would suggest using a special class named `ForumPost` so you can do `$forumPost->createPost(/*post data*/);` while the `FormPost` contains a reference to the `database` to process the requests. this will give your code better structure.

Comment: I am trying to make my code based on conventions, so even though it is opinion based, my question is what is the most common way... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataMapper (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). It is a layer between Entities and the Database. On this Class `PostMapper` you have the methods `__construct(\PDO $pdo)`, `create($post)`, `delete($post)`, `save($post)` and `update($post)`. All methods gets the Post Object which will be saved on the database. On each method you do the handling for database.

To prepare and execute the database queries you can use PDO. You don't have to use your own implementation.

Hope it helps for new ideas.

Comment: It is helpful, but it is rather a small application with few files and I really do not want to use third-party stuff. But maybe for a bigger app I will use it. Thanks. :)
And do not forget to vote for the question! :)